# Subscription is not working using Instagram API

Tags: php, api, instagram, instagram-api

I'm trying to get posts of users who adds new photo in Instagram. So I am using Instagram's [Subscription](https://www.instagram.com/developer/subscriptions/) API. I'm sending request based on below code.

```
curl -F 'client_id=CLIENT-ID' \
 -F 'client_secret=CLIENT-SECRET' \
 -F 'object=user' \
 -F 'object_id=user' \
 -F 'aspect=media' \
 -F 'verify_token=myVerifyToken' \+
 -F 'callback_url=[SITE URL]/subscription-callback.php' \
 https://api.instagram.com/v1/subscriptions/
```

After this request I'm getting below response with object_id null and subscription ID is 0.

```
[0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 0
                [type] => subscription
                [object] => user
                [object_id] => 
                [aspect] => media
                [subscription_id] => 0
                [callback_url] => [SITE URL]/subscription-callback.php
            )
```

When this user upload photo then I didn't get any data in [SITE URL]/subscription-callback.php

Also is there any way to subscribe for all users who authenticated my app at one time?

Comment: Did that user authorize your app and grant it the permission necessary to access the content in question?

Comment: _“Also is there any way to subscribe for all users who authenticated my app at one time?”_ - that’s actually what they _start with_ on the very documentation page you linked to. Only later on they explain how to subscribe for an individual user.

Comment: Yes, user authorised the app. In the response i'm getting 0 as subscription_id so I think there will be some issue.

Comment: In some articles I saw that they send the object_id to subscribe a user.